# NSTableView overlay

Tags: cocoa, overlay, nstableview

Id like to add an overlay to an NSTableView when it is loading some data. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246609/how-to-add-a-blurred-view-ontop-of-a-view) post which mentions using `CALayer` with a `CIGaussianBlur` but I cannot get anything to work. Does anyone know of any good tutorials for displaying an overlay on an NSTableView? (Or even just an NSView).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always found it easiest to do this by not futzing with the table view at all. Embed the table as a subview of another view (a container view, if you will). Add another subview to the container view that will be your overlay, just make sure it's in front of your table. Then you hide the overlay view when you don't need it, show it when you do.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did just this and its working great.